# DAX - summarize by averaged column

Tags: dax

I'm new to DAX, and struggling how to summarize by calculated column using DAX.
In my dataset below, how can I calculate the average sales by price point using DAX?

Limitations is that I cannot add `price` column (value / unit) on my DB.
Thus, I need to calculate both `price` and `sales by price` in one DAX query.

| Week | Value | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| W1 | 3000 | 3 |
| W2 | 1500 | 1 |
| W3 | 500 | 1 |
| W4 | 1500 | 1 |
| W5 | 2000 | 2 |

The result should be like this:

| Price | Avg Value Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | 500 |
| 1000 | 2500 |
| 1500 | 1500 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have a Price column, you cannot create a matrix visual with the price on the rows, since measures cannot be used for the columns. But you can implement a calculated table like this

```
Result = 
VAR Tab =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( Prices, "Price", Prices[Value] / Prices[Unit] )
VAR Res =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        Tab,
        "Avg",
            VAR CurPrice = [Price]
            RETURN
                AVERAGEX ( FILTER ( Tab, [Price] = CurPrice ), Prices[Value] )
    )
RETURN
    DISTINCT ( SELECTCOLUMNS ( Res, "Price", [Price], "Avg", [Avg] ) )
```

First we declare a table variable from the source table (I called it "Prices") adding the Price column, then we iterate over this table variable adding the "Avg" column using `AVERAGEX` on the same table variable filtered by "Price". Finally we return the `DISTINCT` of the two columns Price and Avg.

Edit:
It's possible to reduce the number of rows adding a variable to get the distinct prices

```
Result1 = 
VAR Tab =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( Prices, "Price", Prices[Value] / Prices[Unit] )
VAR DistinctPrices = DISTINCT( SELECTCOLUMNS( Tab, "Price", [Price] ) )
VAR Res =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        DistinctPrices,
        "Avg",
            VAR CurPrice = [Price]
            RETURN
                AVERAGEX ( FILTER ( Tab, [Price] = CurPrice ), Prices[Value] )
    )
RETURN
    DISTINCT ( SELECTCOLUMNS ( Res, "Price", [Price], "Avg", [Avg] ) )
```

Comment: One question: is there more efficient query? In my understanding, your answer makes redundant calculation of Avg sales for duplicated rows. The query took too lon time to execute since my dataset has more than millions of records...

Comment: I'm afraid that a more performing solution would require to add a column with the price or to create calculated table in the model. If this in an imported model it can be done without touching the original table.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, there is a possible optimization to reduce redundancy without the need to add calculated columns